# ERROR VQGAN + CLIP Loading libraries and definitions

Tags: python-imaging-library

I'm a design student and I'm trying to use VQGAN+CLIP to generate some images. I copied the doc and run all the cells but when I tried to run the Loading libraries and definitions cell, there is this message :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-c026441db553> in <cell line: 13>()
     11 from omegaconf import OmegaConf
     12 from PIL import Image
---> 13 from taming.models import cond_transformer, vqgan
     14 import torch
     15 from torch import nn, optim

7 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/PIL/ImageFont.py in <module>
     32 
     33 from . import Image
---> 34 from ._util import isDirectory, isPath
     35 
     36 LAYOUT_BASIC = 0

ImportError: cannot import name 'isDirectory' from 'PIL._util' (/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/PIL/_util.py)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NOTE: If your import is failing due to a missing package, you can
manually install dependencies using either !pip or !apt.

To view examples of installing some common dependencies, click the
"Open Examples" button below.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

How can I fix this? I don't know how to code and english isn't my native language so please if you know the solution could you explain it to me step to step ? Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

you can add this two code

!pip install pytorch-lightning==1.6.5

!pip install --upgrade Pillow